# Set an active workspace in a shell script on Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script whose sole purpose is to launch a deterministic code. When running, the latest opens a few non-interactive terminals, which can be a pain.

I am working on Linux CentOS with a few different workspaces. Consequently I want to make it so that the shell script will consider one of my workspaces as the "active workspace" instead of the one I am currently working on; the non interactive terminals will then open in this other workspace.

I already looked into "wmctrl -s" but it has to switch the workspace I am currently on.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Don't launch the terminals. Looks like you are mixing the terms *shell* and *terminal*. When you want to run code in a shell, you don't need to spawn a terminal, you just need to spawn a shell.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough : the shell script is used to launch an other code. This code, while running prompt some non interactive terminal windows I have no control on.

Comment: Do you always have to watch the non interactive terminal ? Or just not bother your workspace ?

Comment: It is more like not bothering my workspace.

Comment: @JohnDoe Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is using [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).
It creates virtual X display which is not visible to you.
After installing Xvfb, using `xvfb-run` is convenient.

```
xvfb-run -n 98 -- ./your_script.sh
```

should do the job. it displays the terminal inside the non-visible virtual X display.

If you want to watch the terminal inside Xvfb, you may use [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).

run Xvfb with in display `:3`

```
Xvfb :3 -screen scrn 1924x1024x24
```

start VNC server,

```
x11vnc -display :3 -rfbport 25900
```

and run the script

`DISPLAY=:3 ./your_script.sh`

you can use any VNC client and connect to `25900` port to watch it.